# Changing the stroke color for an inline SVG

Tags: jquery, css, svg, sublimetext2

**Issue 1**

I'm trying to change the stroke color of an inline svg on hover. It's a path exported from Illustrator and put through Peter Collingridge's SVG optimiser. The articles I read on styling inline SVG are very straight forward but the techniques won't work on my SVG.

I have placed a hover pseudo-class on the  tag and can't seem to target the stroke.

```
<svg class="highlight" width="86" height="68" viewBox="0 0 85.7 68.5">
  <polygon points="11 60.7 74.7 60.7 42.8 4.4 " style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:#491EC4"/>
</svg>
```

I set the background-color to pink to check that hover is working and that's fine.

```
.highlight:hover {
  background-color: pink;
  stroke: red;
}
```

Here it is on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duyenho/ojn8r810/1/).

I also tried to wrap the polygon in a use tag with an id to change the stroke in CSS as well as adding the svg selector with stroke:inherit, as suggested in a Codrops article. Also, jQuery's hover method with no luck.

What am I doing wrong and why are these three techniques not working?

**Issue 2**

Sublime Text 2 won't recognise the stroke property. It comes up white when I type it in CSS and HTML. Does this mean it's invalid? I looked at the README file for a CSS3 plugin to see what it's adding and there's no "stroke" property. Should I be using Sublime Text 3 in beta?

All these things...

Comment: I would strongly recommend upgrading to Sublime Text 3 (ST3) regardless - there are an incredible number of improvements over 2, which was released *three years ago*. I've been using 3 for years, and it's rock-steady - it still has the "beta" tag, but it was out of beta long ago. All development work is now focused on ST3 - [*`"I don't know of any good reason to not use Sublime Text 3"`*](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-2-not-developed-anymore/18680/4) - Will Bond, ST core developer. Additionally, ST2 is [no longer the default download](https://sublimetext.com).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The CSS in the SVG is *inline* CSS and so is being applied **after** your stylesheet and thus is overriding it.

The simplest solution is to extract the CSS from the SVG and put it all in your stylesheet.

```css
.highlight {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: #491EC4;
}

.highlight:hover {
  /* background-color: pink; */
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="highlight" width="86" height="68" viewBox="0 0 85.7 68.5">
  <polygon points="11 60.7 74.7 60.7 42.8 4.4 " />
</svg>
```

Comment: Well. It didn't work. When I extract the css rules outside, the rules are not applied to the svg anymore.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to select the polygon tag, since that tag is styled to have a stroke.
Since it's been decorated with an inline style, your css rule should use `!important` in order to override the inline style.

```css
.highlight:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}
.highlight:hover polygon{
  stroke: red !important;
}
```

```html
<svg class="highlight" width="86" height="68" viewBox="0 0 85.7 68.5">
  <polygon points="11 60.7 74.7 60.7 42.8 4.4 " style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:#491EC4"/>
</svg>
```

Disclaimer: It would be preferable to extract the inline styles and move them to their own css files (as mentioned by [Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37940608/1203738)). If by any means extracting is not possible, you could go with `!important`

Answer (score 3):

the style property in your html overwrite your css selectors. So include all your style properties in the css.

Check the jsfiddle link ;)

https://jsfiddle.net/ojn8r810/3/

HTML

```
<svg class="highlight" width="86" height="68" viewBox="0 0 85.7 68.5">
  <polygon points="11 60.7 74.7 60.7 42.8 4.4 "/>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
.highlight { 
  fill:none;
  stroke-width:3px;
  stroke:#491EC4;
}
.highlight:hover {
  background-color: pink;
  stroke: red;
}
```