# SVG stroke color won't change

Tags: css, svg, colors, stroke

I'm having trouble getting the stroke color on an SVG to change. Here I have an SVG from the Material Symbols library that displays in black:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
<path d="M280-600v-80h560v80H280Zm0 160v-80h560v80H280Zm0 160v-80h560v80H280ZM160-600q-17 0-28.5-11.5T120-640q0-17 11.5-28.5T160-680q17 0 28.5 11.5T200-640q0 17-11.5 28.5T160-600Zm0 160q-17 0-28.5-11.5T120-480q0-17 11.5-28.5T160-520q17 0 28.5 11.5T200-480q0 17-11.5 28.5T160-440Zm0 160q-17 0-28.5-11.5T120-320q0-17 11.5-28.5T160-360q17 0 28.5 11.5T200-320q0 17-11.5 28.5T160-280Z"/>
</svg>
```

I have modified it by adding `stroke="#ff0000"` attribute to both the `<svg>` and `<path>` tag with no effect. I have also tried `stroke="currentColor"` and set the color attribute of the parent via CSS with no effect.

I have read the replies on various stackoverflow questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37940282/changing-the-stroke-color-for-an-inline-svg), but none of the suggestions have worked for me yet.

I have no idea what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: try fill instead of stroke

Comment: For a single ``d`` path paste it into https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/# and check the viewBox dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stroke` attribute refers to the outline of the `path` element. You can see the effect your `stroke="#ff0000"` change has had by adding `stroke-width="10"`. However, this is probably not what you intended.

Instead, if you add a `fill="#ff0000"` you will change the color of the path itself. This is most likely what you wanted.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
<path fill="#ff0000" d="M280-600v-80h560v80H280Zm0 160v-80h560v80H280Zm0 160v-80h560v80H280ZM160-600q-17 0-28.5-11.5T120-640q0-17 11.5-28.5T160-680q17 0 28.5 11.5T200-640q0 17-11.5 28.5T160-600Zm0 160q-17 0-28.5-11.5T120-480q0-17 11.5-28.5T160-520q17 0 28.5 11.5T200-480q0 17-11.5 28.5T160-440Zm0 160q-17 0-28.5-11.5T120-320q0-17 11.5-28.5T160-360q17 0 28.5 11.5T200-320q0 17-11.5 28.5T160-280Z"/>
</svg>
```

For more on the differences between `fill` and `stroke` see [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes).